# android phonegap jquery click on element in dynamic list

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, html-lists

I am trying to achieve a click that triggers a function on a list element. The list is populated on runtime. I am using jQuery 1.8.0 and PhoneGap 2.0.

```
    $(".myList").on("click", "li", function(event) {
       $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 150).queue(function() {
          someFunc((this).attr("id"));
       });
    });
```

When testing it on Android using PhoneGap the function is triggered with the correct param of the id of the clicked li element but the whole list gets a blue click effect (in addition to the jquery effect of the clicked li element). When testing it in the firefox there is no blue click effect on the whole list, just the jquery highlight effect. Has anyone a clue why there is a difference on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a blue click effect on all list; because you're binding a `click` event to whole list and then delegate to `li` elements. Android browser highlights tapped areas as a default behaviour. However, you can override this via CSS -`webkit-tap-highlight-color` property like this:

```
.myList {
  webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

Comment: I get the blue effect only on certain Android devices. I get it using a Galaxy 1 with Android 2.3.6 but not on my Galaxy SII with 4.1.1 or another Galaxy with 4.0.3. But using this line, it works everywhere, thx. :)